# Navbar Branding not showing up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a navbar-brand setup on my navbar, but the link's just get pushed to the left and a navbar-brand is nowhere to be seen.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="override">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" href="#">Alpha Creations</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                    <ul class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-nav nav" id="override">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services" id="nav-services"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio" id="navbar-portfolio"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#packages" id="navbar-packages"><i class="fa fa-money"></i>Pricing &amp; Packages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#reviews" id="navbar-reviews"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>Customer Reviews</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Edit:
The links were just a matter of CSS but the branding still doesn't show up

Thanks Xufox, i'm not entirely sure how to properly post the markup

Comment: If your website is this one: http://disputebills.com/ I do see your brand on the far left.

Comment: Woops, thats not my website. I copied someone's branding to see if that worked.

Comment: What would your website be exactly, or do you have anything that can show us what you mean?

Comment: http://wolfservers.net/hydra/at-gfx/

Comment: I've also noticed that any image branding just goes behind the navbar, instead of on top of it

Comment: So just to be clear your end goal is to have a logo on the left of the navigation bar?